# /var directory and redis

Tags: filesystem, ram

In terms of the filesystem hierarchy standard, the /var directory contains variable files — files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system— such as logs, spool files, and temporary e-mail files.

Now if you read the redis documentation:

http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

There is this line:

```
Create a directory where to store your Redis config files and your data:
sudo mkdir /etc/redis
sudo mkdir /var/redis
```

Now the config files obviously go in /etc. But it says "store your data in /var". What does it mean by that? The way redis works is that the data is stored in RAM, not on the disk. So what data is it referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way redis works is that the data is stored in RAM, not on the disk.

`/var` is not mounted in RAM, its content persist between reboots.

Usually web servers store their pages in /var/www, database managers store data in /var/lib/*name* (/var/lib/mysql, for example)...

It's absolutely normal applications store data inside /var.

Comment: Do you know dump.rdb is?

Comment: No, but I found [this](http://redis.io/topics/persistence). Look for "dump.rdb".

Comment: That's cool, so basically it takes snapshots of the data in memory and saves them on disc periodically.